# Trigger `npm install` for a certain directory in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, npm, npm-install

I'm in a shell script running in `~/folder1/` and I'd like to trigger `npm install` in `~/folder2/`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `(cd ~/folder2/;npm install)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--prefix` option:

```
npm install --prefix ~/folder2/ packagename
```

You just have to omit the `packagename` to install from the `package.json`

```
npm install --prefix ~/folder2/
```

Comment: I don't want to install a package, just run `npm install` on the `package.json` inside `folder2`

Comment: Ah nice one. It works although it's not listed in [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install). Is there a doc for this flag?

Comment: You're right, this flag is not very [well documented](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11007).

Comment: It's a ghost flag. ermuhgerd.